# Cascade error with a mandatory one-to-many relationship

Tags: sails.js

I am using Sails 1.1.0. I tried the below with `sails-disk` and `sails-mongo` adapter.

I created a mandatory-one-to-many rerlationship. A `Sofa` has `owner` which is one-to-many to `User` and a `Sofa` also has a `home` which is one-to-many with `Home`. However when I `await Home.destroy(homeId);` the `Home`, its not cascading down and deleting the `Sofa`. Instead I get error:

```
PropagationError: Failed to run the "cascade" polyfill.  Could not propagate the potential destruction of this home record.
Details:
  Cannot wipe the contents of association (`sofas`) because there is one conflicting shame record whose `home` cannot be set to `null`.  (That attribute is required.)

This error originated from the fact that the "cascade" polyfill was enabled for this query.
Tip: Try reordering your .destroy() calls.
 [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for more help.
```

Here are my model associations:

```
// api\models\Sofa.js

    owner: {
      model: 'user',
      required: true
    },

    home: {
      model: 'home',
      required: true
    },

// api\models\User.js    

        sofas: {
           collection: 'sofa',
           via: 'owner'
        },

// api\models\Home.js    

        sofas: {
           collection: 'sofa',
           via: 'home'
        },
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use `.archive()` instead?

Comment: Thanks @Raqem I will try and let you know. However `.archive()` is not what I need. But i understand you, doing this test will teach us more about the problem right?

Comment: @Raqem I tried `await Home.archive(homeId).meta({ cascade: true })`, please notice the `archive`, I got same error. :( Any ideas?

Comment: Updated topic to mention I'm using `sails-disk`, I'm not sure if this might have something to do with it.

Comment: Updated topic to mention I tested the above with `sails-mongo` and same situation. :(

Comment: in your `config/locals/modals.js` do you have `cascadeOnDestroy: true` ?

Comment: @Raqem I do not, but I thought if i added to the destory call `.meta({ cascade:true })` isn't this also equivalent?

Comment: @Raqem I just checked `config/models.js` and yes `cascadeOnDestroy: true` is set.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, looking at the documentation for casade, it says "Thus deleting a record with a 2-way, plural association (one-to-many or many-to-many) will also cleanly remove all links to other records (by removing join table rows or setting foreign key values to null)". I would hazard a guess, that in your case it is simply attempting to set foreign key in Sofa to null which is throwing your error. Although not ideal, you could instead add a beforeDestroy lifecycle callback to do the deletion process for you. I believe this was the only way to handle this in sails versions < 1.

Comment: Thanks for asking @Glen - I haven't resolved this yet :( I am using sails-mongo now and am still having this problem.

Comment: Yea, so a little further digging on the Sails [Trello](https://trello.com/c/16bayYNm/244-docs-cascading-delete-polyfill-via-the-cascadeondestroy-model-setting-mainly-for-development-and-for-mongo-users-docs-ought-to-a) and I believe it works as I thought, the cascade is attempting to set the Home reference in Sofa to null. I was thinking of another solution, could you remove `required : true` from the home reference in Sofa and then trigger a clean up action that deletes all Sofas where the home reference is null.

Comment: Thanks Glen!! Things actually changed drastically so I can't test this verbatim right now, but when I get across this error again I'll definitely give it a look and report back. Thanks Glen for helping me with an unresolved issue, unresolved issues really bother me haha.

Comment: Haha. I live by the moto "if it's not broke, fix it until it is".

Comment: HAHAHA!!! @Glen

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently, using sails-disk adapter with `inMemoryOnly: true` option, you don't need to clean the database because is memory only and when test is finished it will be cleaned automatically.

```
datastores: {
  default: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk',
    inMemoryOnly: true
  },
}
```

Comment: I think they fixed this issue in latest version of sails-disk, im not sure if they published the fix though.